# ¿Por qué PHP me genera un 1 en mi template?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un proyecto de práctica con PHP y he estado tratando de entender el por qué se renderiza un número 1 en mi template, siendo que no tengo metido en ningún lado eso.

¿Alguien sabría la causa?

[image: Print del código del template de footer]

[image: Print de la pantalla]

En el último print se puede ver como se renderiza el 1 de la nada y no logro comprender el porque.

Comment: Hola, en una próxima recuerda agregar el código con el formato apropiado según las reglas de la comunidad en lugar de usar screenshots.

Comment: Tenes toda la razón, gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionar y dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le pase lo mismo.

Este código, `<?= ?>`, tiene un `echo` implícito y como al estar trayendo otros archivos con ese código, este me hacía `echo` y me renderizaba un 1. Lo pude resolver cambiando a la expresión clásica, la cual no tiene un echo por detrás `<?php ?>`.